# glob in spark 3.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I used to run glob to get the file path under Spark 2.0+.

```py
glob.glob("/dbfs/mnt/.../*/Acquisition*.txt")
```

After upgrading to Spark 3.0, this command didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: folder to ** not * and test please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) of the version for python 3.8 that is a bit different from the version for python 2.7

You should use `**` for the recursive path and also have to turn on the option `recursive=True`. Then,

```py
glob.glob('/path/from/root/**/Acquisition*.txt', recursive=True)
```